# Некорректно работает Яндекс.Карта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На [**странице**](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/dev/Bukvogramma/) в футере есть кнопка **"Показать на карте"**.
При клике во всплывающем окне отображается карта.

У карты **2 проблемы**:

1. Если закрыть окно, а потом открыть, то карта уже не отображается.
2. Если уменьшать окно браузера (страница адаптивная), то карта не уменьшается, и появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Но если окно увеличивать, то и карта тоже растягивается.

**Как это можно исправить?**

Comment: **проблема №1** не воспроизводится.

Comment: А можно на код глянуть?

Comment: Проблема №2 решается выставлением адаптивной ширины `#map > ymaps { width: 100% !important; }` и  `#map > ymaps > ymaps { width: 100% !important; }`